# Saving and accessing data from service in angular 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I recently started looking in to the latest version of angular with the new syntax, but I'm familiar with Angular v1.

I'm working on an ionic(v4.12.0) project, below is the sample angular(v7.2.15) service `TodoService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  private todos = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Constructor TodoService');
  }

  list() {
    // log shows this.todos as empty, always
    return this.todos;
  }

  add(todo object) {
    this.todos.push(todo);
    // log shows this.todos having 1 element now. it never goes beyond 1 irrespective of the number of todos added from the modal form 
  }

}
```

I've created a modal `TodoAddPage` to read from a form and add an entry to the `todos` in `TodoService`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';

@Component({})
export class TodoAddPage implements OnInit {
    constructor(
      private modalController: ModalController,
      private todoService: TodoService
    ) {}

    close() {
      this.modalController.dismiss({
        dismissed: true
      });
    }

    onSubmit(todo: object) {
      this.todoService.add(todo);
      this.close();
    }
}
```

A page `TodosPage` to list the todos from the `TodoService`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TodoAddPage } from './todo-add.page';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';

@Component({})
export class TodosPage implements OnInit {

  public todos = [];

  constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private todoService: TodoService
  ) {
    this.todos = this.todoService.list();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async add() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: TodoAddPage,
      componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });

    await modal.present();

    const { data } = await modal.onWillDismiss();
    console.log(data);

    console.log(this.todoService.list()); // Issues: This is always empty
  }

}
```

The issue is the `TodoService.list()` always returns empty list. I checked adding logs in the `TodoService.add` function. And the data seems to be in the `TodoService.todos` after the `.push` in the `.add` function. But event if I access it immediately closing the modal, the content returned by the `.list()` function is empty.

The behavior seems a bit weird, has anyone run in to this issue ? or am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz so that we can run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

While posting the question, I abstracted out the component definition like below

```
@Component({})
export class TodoAddPage implements OnInit {}
```

But the actual content of `Component` was

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-add',
  templateUrl: './todo-add.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-add.page.scss'],
  providers: [TodoService] // This was the one causing the issue
})
```

Removed the providers (not sure when or why I added there) in the above and it solved the issue.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-add',
  templateUrl: './todo-add.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-add.page.scss'],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling services you have two options.

**Option 1** Access the todos list itself. This is the best case to get predefined todos:

```js
 constructor(private todoService: TodoService){
    this.todos = this.todoService.todos;
  }
```

**Option 2** Define todos as BehaviorSubject and subscribe to this particular subject and deal with changes so you don't have to create a getter method for todos.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  private todos = [];
  todosSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  list(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.todosSubject.asObservable();
  }

  add(todo: any) {
    this.todos.push(todo);
    this.todosSubject.next(this.todos);
  }

}
```

and in your page call the subscribe to the list function:

```js
  public todos = [];

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController, private todoService: TodoService) 
  {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  getTodos()
  {
    this.todoService.list().subscribe((data) => { this.todos = data });
  }
```

Hope this answers your question.